# Django rest swagger common documentation python

Tags: python, django, rest, yaml, swagger

I am using django-rest-swagger in my django app for api documentation. I have a common YAML structure for all post and put calls.

The problem that I am facing is that I have to write the same docstring in all create and update methods of the viewset class.

I want to write a generic method for this. But I couldn't find a way to do that.

I want through the [Django Rest Framework Doc](http://django-rest-swagger.readthedocs.io/en/latest/yaml.html) but couldn't find anything useful.

Comment: Do the routines already have YAML comments that can be updated (and especially: *recognised*), or do the API calls have no docstring at all yet (which would require recognising the `def xxxxx` beginning of the calls)?

Comment: API calls have comments (python docstrings). I heard YAML was deprecated in swagger 2.0